# s3 policy for deny put object and get object if not sending the KMS id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

below is my policy for deny put object, if user not providing the sse kms id. this one is working fine.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1631518070654",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1631518063107",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "arn:xxx"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

also i'm trying to deny in get object if user not providing the sse kms id. in below policy i coudln't save in aws. it give me this error -  Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement

```
   {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1631518070654",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1631518063107",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: @luk2302 yes. i updated the code. but still got the error

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to restrict the KMS key during GetObject. In theory if they attempted to use the wrong key the decryption would fail. But they cannot even specify a key during the GetObject in the first place.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html says

> Encryption request headers, like x-amz-server-side-encryption, should not be sent for GET requests if your object uses server-side encryption with KMS keys (SSE-KMS) or server-side encryption with Amazon S3–managed encryption keys (SSE-S3). If your object does use these types of keys, you’ll get an HTTP 400 BadRequest error.